# Additive functors from the category of free abelian groups are right adjoints?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, adjoint-functors

I am reading *Lectures on algebraic topology* by Albrecht Dold. Let $t$ be an additive functor from the category of free abelian groups to the category of abelian groups. In VI 7.3 he writes:

> For any pair $(X, A)$ the sequence $$0\rightarrow SA\rightarrow SX\rightarrow S(X,A)\rightarrow 0$$
> is exact and splits in every dimension. Since $t$ is applied dimension-wise the sequence
> $$0\rightarrow tSA
> \rightarrow
> tSX
> \rightarrow
> tS(X, A) \rightarrow 0 $$ is also exact (and splits
> in every dimension).

I am not sure what exactly he uses to come to this conclusion. I know that for the tensor product we can argue that it is a left adjoint, hence right exact and free abelian groups are flat, hence the result follows, but in general I don't see why this should hold.

The property we need seems to that $t$ is a right adjoint. Is this true or is this too strong of an assumption?

Notation:

- We have pair $(X,A)$ if $X$ is a topological space and $A$ a subspace.
- $SX$ is the chain complex consisting of free abelian groups $S_nX$ generated by the singular $n$-simplices of $X$.
- $S(X,A)$ is the chain complex $SX/SA$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, an additive functor $t$ preserves split short exact sequences (just apply the functor $t$ to the algebraic equations that capture being a split short exact sequence). Thus, each component $t_n$ of the functor $t$ preserves the corresponding split short exact sequence.

Comment: Exact functors preserve all short exact sequences (by definition). Additive functors preserve the split ones.

Comment: Exactly. Just to add a bit more detail, the fact that an additive functor preserves the zero module is crucial when proving that being split is preserved (at least the proof I know).

Comment: Why is $t$ an exact functor?

Comment: @JarneRenders $t$ is not necessarily exact, but it is enough that it is additive.